# Regular expression - starting and ending with a character string

Tags: regex, string

I would like to write a regular expression that starts with the string "wp" and ends with the string "php" to locate a file in a directory. How do I do it?

Example file: wp-comments-post.php

Comment: There ia a good tutorial here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Why regex? Wouldn't you rather use globbing when looking for files?

Comment: How would you do it using globbing?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

This should do it for you `^wp.*php$`

Matches

```
wp-comments-post.php
wp.something.php
wp.php
```

Doesn't match

```
something-wp.php
wp.php.txt
```

Answer (score 59):

`^wp.*\.php$`  Should do the trick.

The `.*` means "any character, repeated 0 or more times". The next `.` is escaped because it's a special character, and you want a literal period (".php"). Don't forget that if you're typing this in as a literal string in something like C#, Java, etc., you need to escape the backslash because it's a special character in many literal strings.

Comment: This should also work:

    ^wp.+\.php$

The only difference is the '+', which makes the dot "greedy".

Comment: @AdamHowell `+` and `*` are both greedy, although greediness doesn't make a difference in this case. The difference is that `*` matches zero or more characters, and the `+` matches one or more characters. So if someone wanted to match "wp.php", they should use `*`; if they specifically wanted to not match that, they should use `+`.

Answer (score 14):

Example: 
ajshdjashdjashdlasdlhdlSTARTasdasdsdaasdENDaknsdklansdlknaldknaaklsdn

1) `START\w*END`
return: STARTasdasdsdaasdEND - will give you words between START and END

2) `START\d*END`
return: START12121212END - will give you numbers between START and END

3) `START\d*_\d*END`
return: START1212_1212END - will give you numbers between START and END having _