# How to check that whole string matching to pattern instead find substrings that matching using NSRegularExpression?

Tags: objective-c, nsregularexpression

`NSRegularExpression` class has methods for searching substrings that matching to pattern, eg `- numberOfMatchesInString:options:range:`

But what can I do if I want to check whole string for matching with pattern?
In my case, I need check entered number for its length was 6..10 digits and no more any other symbols.

My code can check minimum string length:

```
NSUInteger min = 6, max = 10;
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\d{%u,%u}", min, max];
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *number = [_numberTextField text];
NSUInteger matches = [re numberOfMatchesInString:number options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [number length])];
```

But it can find extra symbol, number or other because of string has matching substring.

Eg if I entered `12345` regex will say that string has no matches
With `12345678901` value (11 digits) result will be 1 match, but in this case string length is larger than 10 and I want result

Comment: You may want to use `^\\d{%u,%u}$`, with `^` for the start, and `$` for the end?

Comment: Thank you @Larme, it helped me!
Write this in answer and I will check it

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate since it's for the Regular Expression part, and not specially linked to iOS. The second answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024370/1801544) explains the `^`and `$`. As https://regex101.com does if you put it in the pattern.

Comment: In other languages regular expression classes usually has method that check whole string, and my question was about such method in objective-c. Your comment helped me, but it's a bypass of my problem.

Comment: If you look at the documentation of NSRegularExpression `^` and `$` are given. So I don't think that it really "bypass" your issue. There is also a option `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines`, but I didn't check how it works. In your particular case, I would have used a `decimalDigitCharacterSet`, and check the length rather than using a `NSRegularExpression`.