# Regular Expression To Find a Substring from a text with a particular matches, the sequence may come multiple times in the text

Tags: java, regex, string

I've a variable of type String.

```
String a = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>&nbsp;${member.activation_date}&nbsp;&nbsp;${member.activationdate}&nbsp;</body></html>";
```

Now I want to fetch all the words starting with the $ and ending with a, I have a regular expression which works like a charm `(\$\{\w+\.\w+\})` but is there any other better way to do so which can save me the second \w to make it efficient.

Comment: Regexp: `\$\{([\w.])+\}`

Comment: Not much, I've been using split to break it in small junks and fetch the words... 
But it takes time and code is kind of lengthy. I am totally naive to regex...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression - starting and ending with a character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024298/regular-expression-starting-and-ending-with-a-character-string)

Comment: No, not a duplicate.  That Q asks about matching an entire string against a pattern, OP clearly asking for just a substring.  None of the answers there apply.

Comment: It really hurts when someone down votes a question... Is this the way u encourage newbies...

Comment: This is the way we encourage newbies to ask proper questions.  You really should put more effort into this, there's tons of regex tutorials on the web.  (And no, I did not down-vote.)

Comment: Try it like this [`\${[^}]+}`](https://regex101.com/r/Q6JDMw/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird `{` is also special character which requires escaping (at least in regex flavor used in Java).

Comment: Very gud. It really helps. Maybe you are repaying the way u were treated. No worries... Please downvote it 100 more times, if it makes u feel good :)

Comment: @Thefourthbird majid is probably trying to create something similar to EL expressions and that regexp matches other characters than words, for eg it also matches white space characters.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat You are right, it also matches whitespaces. Your regex would be a better solution.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat $\d*.\d*} what about this one.....!!!

Comment: I think that won't work, did you tried running it?

Comment: I've come with a regex and it works great. Thank you for helping me out.
 (\$\{\w+\.\w+\})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't get my desired answer rather got multiple downvotes, I am accepting this one...
`(\$\{\w+\.\w+\})`
Thank you all for your answers.