# Extract all m3u8 links from text with PHP

Tags: php

I need your help
I want to extract all m3u8 links From Text

```
$string = "http://exemple.com/file/01.mp4 ,http://exemple.com/file/02.m3u8 , http://exemple.com/file/01.mp3 ,http://exemple.com/file/05.m3u8 ,http://exemple.com/file/02.mp4" ;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression - starting and ending with a character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024298/regular-expression-starting-and-ending-with-a-character-string)

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working :)

Steps :

- Remove all spaces.
- Split when there is a ",".
- Create an array and fill it only with url finishing with .m3u8.
- You get your ".m3u8" urls :).

---

```
<?php

$string = "http://exemple.com/file/01.mp4 ,http://exemple.com/file/02.m3u8 , http://exemple.com/file/01.mp3 ,http://exemple.com/file/05.m3u8 ,http://exemple.com/file/02.mp4" ;

$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);

$urls = explode( ",", $string);

$result = [];
foreach ($urls as $url){
 if( substr($url, -5) == ".m3u8") array_push($result, $url);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this code to do the same work? Your style is good, but the text problem may be messy.      preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);